# How to tunnel a URL that is hidden behind an AWS security group through a tunnel server that has access?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, ssh, reverse-proxy, ssh-tunnel

I have a tunnel server within the security group of an AWS ELB, I have an `ingress` that resolves domain names and directs the request to the correct service.

If I ssh into the tunnel server, I can do `curl internal-url.mycompany.com/ping` and it will work.

I would like to do something like: `sudo ssh -i key.pem -N -L 80:localhost:80 user@tunnel-server`
(`sudo` because it's a privileged port)

Then on my local machine invoke `curl internal-url.mycompany.com/ping` but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

What you have in your question is almost exactly what you would need.  `sudo ssh -i key.pem -N -L 80:internal-url.mycompany.com:80 user@tunnel-server` should proxy requests to your machine's `localhost:80` to `internal-url.mycompany.com:80` via the SSH tunnel to your tunnel-server.

Comment: The problem is if we did this, we can hit the AWS ELB, but it has an nginx reverse proxy looking for "internal-url.mycompany.com"